# Moving objects in a series of set directions

Tags: java, processing

I am new to coding and struggling with a project. I do not know Java well.

My aim is as follows: monitoring and optimization of a concrete delivery service for construction sites by the company operator (concrete plant and truck suppliers).

I should have a concrete plant, two trucks and several sites that are created thanks to the user's click. The operator can have at any time the vision of the trucks of his company that deliver concrete to the worksites located in a given geographical area. And the number of sites evolves (= click of the user hard the screen).

**Variables**:

Concrete plant -> Coordinates (xCoord, yCoord) + size;

Site(arraylist) -> Coordinates (site.x, site.y or destination.x, destination.y in the lorry class) + size;

Lorry (x2) -> Coordinates (location.x, location.y); size; origin; destination.

**Actions of a lorry**:

move to a site (1)

wait about 3 seconds when it reaches the site

go to the next site of the list (2) (+wait 3secs)

go back to the concrete plant after it reaches 2 sites (wait 3 secs)

go to the next site (3), then (4), go back to concrete plant etc...

(basically it does 2 sites and comes back, 2 site and comes back etc... And it cannot go to a site that has already been delivered).

It would be good also to have the logo of the site change once it has been reached by a lorry.

**Choice of the lorry**: I got 2 lorries and the choice on which lorry to go needs to be made by:

if its free (not already on route to a site);

if it is full (has done 0 or 1 site, or hasn't done 2 sites);

the closest one ( measure the distance).

**Interaction with HTML**:

I was thinking if possible to somehow measure the distance made by each lorries and display it on the HTML screen (and save the data with a keypress if possible).

So I started by looking if I can maybe add a lorry (don't know if its the right part to start on, maybe the actions would be better). And i tried telling it that if the siteNumber is under 2 it goes through the list of sites, but if not the new destination is the concrete plant. But it doesn't work.

So that's my script so far (I have replaced the images of the concrete, site and lorries by ellipses and rectangles so you can run it):

```
/*preload = "factory_12.png";*/
/*preload = "sign.png";*/
/*preload = "simple_truck.png";*/

Lorry lorry;

//PImage concretePlant;
//PFont aFont;
int xCoord;
int yCoord;
ArrayList<Site> sites;
int siteSize = 30;

void setup() // What is called once at the beginning
{
  size (500, 500);

  //concretePlant = loadImage("factory_12.png");
  //aFont = createFont("IndustrialRevolution-Regular", 12);
  //textFont(aFont);

  xCoord = int(width/2);
  yCoord = int(height/2);

  //Creating empty Array List where store sites objects
  sites = new ArrayList<Site>();

  //Adding first site
  sites.add(new Site(random(width), random(height), siteSize));

  //storing lorries
  lorry = new Lorry(xCoord, yCoord);
}

void draw() // Draw the background and concrete plant
{
  background (235, 247, 255); //light blue background, not in draw as it wouldn't allow the site image to stay
  //image(concretePlant, xCoord, yCoord, 60, 60);
  ellipse(xCoord, yCoord, 60, 60);
  //fill(1);
  //text("Concrete Plant", xCoord-20, yCoord+70);

  //Calling the sites
  for (int i = sites.size () - 1; i>=0; i--) {
    Site site = sites.get(i);
    site.displaySites();
  }

  //calling the lorry functions
  lorry.updateLorry();
}

void mousePressed() {
  sites.add(new Site(mouseX, mouseY, siteSize));
}

class Site

{
  float x,y;
  float size;
  //PImage picture;

  Site (float xin, float yin, float sin)
  {
    x = xin;
    y = yin;
    size = sin;
    //picture = loadImage("sign.png");
  }

  void displaySites()
  {
    //image(picture, x, y, 60, 60);
    rect(x, y, 60, 60);
  }
}

class Lorry
{
  PVector location1;
  PVector location2;
  PVector concretePlant;
  //PVector velocity;
  //PImage mixer;
  boolean changeDirection;
  int siteNumber = 0;
  Site destination;

  Lorry(float xCoord, float yCoord)
  {
    concretePlant = new PVector(xCoord, yCoord); //Initial start point
    location1 = new PVector(xCoord, yCoord); //Initial start point
    location2 = new PVector(xCoord, yCoord); //Initial start point
    //velocity = new PVector(2, 2);
    //mixer = loadImage("simple_truck.png");
    destination = sites.get(siteNumber);
    changeDirection = false;
  }

  void displayLorry()
  {
    //image(mixer, location1.x, location1.y, 30, 30);
    //image(mixer, location2.x, location2.y, 30, 30);
    ellipse(location1.x, location1.y, 30, 30);
    ellipse(location2.x, location2.y, 30, 30);
  }

  void Move()
  {
    float xdir1 = destination.x - location1.x;
    float ydir1 = destination.y - location1.y;
    PVector dir1 = new PVector (xdir1, ydir1);
    dir1.normalize();
    location1.add(dir1);
    print("1going");

    float xdir2 = destination.x - location2.x;
    float ydir2 = destination.y - location2.y;
    PVector dir2 = new PVector (xdir2, ydir2);
    dir2.normalize();
    location2.add(dir2);
    print("2going");
  }

  void checkProgress()
  {
    for (int siteNumber = 0; siteNumber < 2; siteNumber = siteNumber++);
    if (dist(destination.x, destination.y, location1.x, location1.y) < 1) {
      if (siteNumber <sites.size() -1) {
        siteNumber++; // siteNumber = siteNumber + 1;
        destination = sites.get(siteNumber);
        changeDirection = true;
        println("1reached final site");
      } else {
        destination.x = concretePlant.x;
        destination.y = concretePlant.y;
        println ("1back to home");
      }
      println("1progress checked ");
    }

    if (dist(destination.x, destination.y, location2.x, location2.y) < 1) {

      if (siteNumber <sites.size() -1) {
        siteNumber++; // siteNumber = siteNumber + 1;
        destination = sites.get(siteNumber);
        changeDirection = true;
        println("2reached final site");
      } else {
        destination.x = concretePlant.x;
        destination.y = concretePlant.y;
        println ("2back to home");
      }
      println("2progress checked ");
    }
  }

  void updateLorry()
  {
    displayLorry();
    Move();
    checkProgress();
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: This question is a bit hard to answer, since there are a lot of subproblems here, and I am not sure which one you're stuck on. Can you cut the descriptive text down to a smaller problem? Is it the location visiting algorithm that you're having trouble with?

Comment: (If this is for an academic assignment and you've been ill, let your educator know, and they may grant you an extension on your deadline.)

Comment: Sorry about the urgent statement, I didn't know. Also it is for an assignment but we are not allowed extensions. I will try to break it down.

Comment: Ok so my problem will first be that I cannot manage to make my lorry come back to the concrete plant after it reaches 2 sites.